# More of my Python code won't do what it's supposed to do, what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

```
money = 170
KitKat = 90
choice1 = raw_input("Choose a snack: ")
```

Choose a snack: KitKat

```
if choice1 < money:
    print ("Enjoy your snack")
else:
    print ("You cannot afford ") + (choice1)
```

You cannot afford KitKat

This is a shortened version of a vending machine programme I am working on. You have a certain amount of coins, and it asks you to choose a snack. In this shortened program you always have 170 coins and you can only choose KitKat. It then checks if you can afford KitKat or not by comparing the variables: "money", and "choice1" to see which is bigger. If "money" is bigger, it should say "Enjoy your snack". But if "choice1" is bigger, it should say "You cannot afford KitKat".

The problem is, when I test it, it always thinks that "choice1" is greater than "money" and tells me that I "cannot afford KitKat".

I think maybe when I am inputting "KitKat" it doesn't recognise it as a variable and compares the word "KitKat" to the variable "money", instead of comparing the variable "KitKat" to the variable "money" But I'm not sure. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Bad indentation. You should indent the code in your blocks

Comment: @Barranka more likely an SO problem than a python one.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Will change that now.

Comment: The `choice1` variable has the value `"KitKat"`. The `KitKat` variable has the value `90`. See the difference?

Comment: Introductory Python names: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not have a dictionary with the prices of various snacks.

i.e instead of

```
KitKat=90
```

have

```
price ={}

price["KitKat"]=90
```

then you can change the line

```
if choice1 < money:
```

to

```
if price[choice1] < money:
```

Comment: I'm a noob to Python so I don't fully understand what's going on here. But it works! So thanks buddy. One more thing, after that bit I have a line: money = money - choice1. The program does a syntax error when I get to that bit.

Comment: @user3937516 remember that `choice1` is a string, and `money` is an int.

Comment: so a dictionary is an object that allows you to look up the value of certain keys. i.e the line price[choice1] < money looks up the value associated with choice1 ( in this case 90) and compares it to money. Before what you were doing was comparing "KitKat" to 90, so it didn't work. Can you see how to use this to fix your line?

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks again user 3684792, and Al.Sal. I should be able to use that dictionary thing to fix the line "money = money - choice1" as well. Maybe "money = money - price[choice1]" would work. Idk, I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going with @user3684792's answer but if you wanted to do it this way you could use

```
choice1 = globals()[raw_input("Choose a snack: ")]
```

but I wouldn't advise it. I imagine it'd cause problems if the user enters unexpected things.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice could be KitKat, but that's still just a string 'KitKat' and isn't linked in anyway to the variable KitKat.

If you're avoiding using dictionaries (the best way to do it) you can use `if` functions.

It's messy but would work.

```
#define all prices
price_kitkat = 90
price_lolly = 12
price_twirl = 100

#define amount of money
money = 170

#Make your choice
choice1 = raw_input("Choose a snack: ")

#Find price of choice
if choice1 == 'KitKat':
    price = price_kitkat
elif choice1 == 'Lolly':
    price = price_lolly
elif choice1 == 'Twirl':
    price = price_twirl
elif choice1 == '':
    print "You didn't choose a snack!"
else:
    print "Your snack doesn't exist!"

#can you afford it?
if price <= money:
    print "You purchased a snack!
else:
    print "You can't afford that!"
```

Comment: Yeah that is really messy. I'll go with the other guy's answer. Thanks though!

Comment: I know his answer was better, the reason I still posted this was in case you had a burning desire to use variables (or if your homework specified you had to!) Learning to use `if` functions is really useful, so understanding how this way works would be pretty good for learning even though I agree with using the other answer)

Comment: Yeah, I understand if functions, it's ok. And the homework doesn't specify anything.